# How can I download my Template Excel .xlxs using OpenXML in .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, openxml, asp.net-3.5

Can anyone help me with my problem when downloading my Excel Template using open XML? I can open the template and I think I also write data to it but I can't download the file to see if data is reflected the cell/row that I want it to display. I called my method from code behind with `EventHandler` as a data type.

Here is my code on the method I'm talking about:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the ExtractJobsCalibrationForm event of the View control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.EventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    void View_ExtractJobsCalibrationForm(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        try
        {
            using (Data.DataContexts.IDataContext objContext = Data.DataContexts.DataContext.CreateDataContext()) 
            {
                GridViewRow row = (((ImageButton)((System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs)(e)).CommandSource).NamingContainer as GridViewRow);

                IQueryable<Data.JobSummary> objJobs = objContext.Jobs.GetJobSummaries().Where(j => !j.IsDeleted);
                IQueryable<Data.EquipmentSummary> objEquipment = objContext.Equipment.GetEquipmentSummaries();

                //oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                //oXL.Visible = true;
                //oXL.DisplayAlerts = false;

                string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Reports/ExcelTemplate/Calibration_Form_ARS-FORM-CL1_Template.xlsx");
                string destPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), string.Format(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path) + "_{0}_{1}{2}", ((HyperLink)row.Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), ".xlsx"));

                //Create a copy from the Template to save the data.
                System.IO.File.Copy(path, destPath, true);

                byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(destPath);

                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    ms.Write(byteArray, 0, (int)byteArray.Length);

                    using (SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(ms, true))
                    {
                        // Access the main Workbook part, which contains all references.
                        WorkbookPart workbookPart = doc.WorkbookPart;
                        // get sheet by name
                        Sheet sheet = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name == "Pre calibration Check in").FirstOrDefault();
                        // get worksheetpart by sheet id
                        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id.Value) as WorksheetPart;
                        // The SheetData object will contain all the data.
                        SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();

                        Cell cell = GetCell(worksheetPart.Worksheet, "B", 2);

                        cell.CellValue = new CellValue("10");
                        cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Number);

                        // Save the worksheet.
                        worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
                        //doc.Close();

                        //Stream stream = File.Open(destPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                        //stream.Close();
                    }

                    File.WriteAllBytes(destPath, ms.ToArray());

                    System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;

                    response.Clear();
                    response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
                    response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Testing.xlsx;");
                    response.Flush();
                    response.BinaryWrite(ms.ToArray());
                    response.End();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException ioEx)
        {
            string openFileName = ioEx.Message.Split('\'')[1].Split('\\')[6];
            //If file is already open, Quit the newly open excel that is with the same filename that is currently open.
            //oXL.Quit();
            //Display the message.
            View.DisplayInformation(string.Format("File ({0}) is already open!", openFileName));
        }
        catch (Exception objException)
        {
            View.DisplayException(objException);
        }
    }
```

and when I run my application there's no file that was downloaded. I'm still stuck with this and don't know how can I make it work. Also, just to inform you that my first code, I'm using Excel Interop but I have a problem when deploying it to the Environment that's why I shift to OpenXML.

EDIT:

Just want to add the `Response Header` of the download:

[image]

as you can see it already has the Content-Disposition and the Content-Length of the file but still nothings happening or no download prompt is display upon clicking the export.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This works for me. Have you stepped through it all the way to Response.End()? If you put a breakpoint in the (Exception) catch block does it get hit? I assume you are not calling this from within an UpdatePanel or something like that?

Comment: hi @Cal279, I don't get any exception. what is happening is that it just keeps loading on the page. Although in the Response Header it already set all Response but still nothings happen. This download is called inside a  `<GridView>` `<TemplateField>`.

Comment: It looks like the prompt to save the download is not being displayed. Have you tried this on other browsers to see what happens?

Comment: hi @Cal279, I already knew what my issue was. It's because I'm downloading the file on the same page and it needs a `Page_Load` to happen because when I try to put my `Response` code in the `Page_Load` it successfully download the file. I just created another web form that will execute the `Response` and I will redirect from it. Thanks for your help again :)